# Capturing screenshot

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to have my program take a screenshot and then format the data in such a way that it can be easily manipulated from my program.

So far I've come up with the following solution:

```
    /**
    * Creates a screenshot of the entire screen
    * @param img - 2d array containing RGB values of screen pixels.
    */
    void get_screenshot(COLORREF** img, const Rectangle &bounds)
    {
        // get the screen DC
        HDC hdc_screen = GetDC(NULL);
        // memory DC so we don't have to constantly poll the screen DC
        HDC hdc_memory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc_screen);
        // bitmap handle
        HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc_screen, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        // select the bitmap handle
        SelectObject(hdc_memory, hbitmap);
        // paint onto the bitmap
        BitBlt(hdc_memory, bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height, hdc_screen, bounds.x, bounds.y, SRCPAINT);
        // release the screen DC
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc_screen);
        // get the pixel data from the bitmap handle and put it into a nice data structure
        for(size_t i = bounds.x; i < bounds.x + bounds.width; ++i)
        {
            for(size_t j = bounds.y; j < bounds.y + bounds.height; ++j)
            {
                img[j-bounds.y][i-bounds.x] = GetPixel(hdc_memory, i, j);
            }
        }
        // release our memory DC
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc_memory);
    }
```

*Note: Rectangle is actually a struct I created with 4 `size_t` fields for the top-left x & y coordinate, and the width and height of the rectangle. It is not the WinAPI Rectangle.

I had a few questions about this code:

1. Am I properly releasing all resources?
2. Is there a better way to do this? I'm looking for something with a similar level of complexity and flexibility a 2d array of RGB values would have. The final screen capture data processing will be done with OpenCL so I would prefer to not have any complicated structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot to `DeleteObject(hbitmap)`.
2. `CreateDIBSection` creates a HBITMAP which data bits are accessible directly through memory pointer, so using it you can avoid the `for` loops completely.
3. Add `CAPTUREBLT` flag along with `SRCCOPY`, otherwise layered (transparent) windows will not be included.
4. Select the bitmap back out of the memory DC after the loop.
5. You should call `DeleteDC` not `ReleaseDC` on the memory DC.  (If you get it, release it.  If you create it, delete it.)

If you want a more efficient approach, you can use a `DIBSECTION` instead of a compatible bitmap.  This would let you skip the slow `GetPixel` loop and get the pixel data written directly into your data structure with the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was just introduced to the wonderful world of [CImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx).

```
    /**
    * Creates a screenshot of the specified region and copies it to the specified region in img.
    */
    void get_screenshot(CImage &img, const CRect & src_bounds, const CRect &dest_bounds)
    {
        // get the screen DC
        HDC hdc_screen = GetDC(nullptr);
        // copy to a CImage
        CImageDC memory_dc(img);
        //StretchDIBits(
        StretchBlt(memory_dc, dest_bounds.left, dest_bounds.top, dest_bounds.Width(), dest_bounds.Height(), hdc_screen, src_bounds.left, src_bounds.top, src_bounds.Width(), src_bounds.Height(), SRCCOPY);
        ReleaseDC(nullptr, memory_dc);
        ReleaseDC(nullptr, hdc_screen);
    }
```

Then to use, just create a `CImage` object, and call `GetBits()` and cast it to something like `char*` and voila. Instant access to the image data.